# Как правильно составить regexp (Python), чтобы запретить спец. символы (\W не подходит)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, запрос, символы, match

Стоит задача: пользователь вводит имя задачи, которое потом будет использовано в качестве шаблона для имени класса Python **2.7** (в Scrapy).
Поэтому необходимо запретить ввод спец. символов.
Пользователь может использовать русские (кроме ь, ё, Ё, ъ) и англ буквы и цифры ( пробел запрещен, разрешено _ ). Главное требование - соблюдение правил Python для идентификатора класса:

> identifier ::= (letter|"") (letter | digit | "")*
>
> letter ::= lowercase | uppercase
>
> lowercase ::= "a"..."z"
>
> uppercase ::= "A"..."Z"
>
> digit ::= "0"..."9"

Пока есть такой вариант "[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][^ ёьъЁ]+$"

`\W` не выход - запрещает русские буквы
т.е. такой вариант не подходит "[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][^ \WёьъЁ]+$"

Цифры в начале можно не фильтровать, т.к. к исходной строке, в начало и в конец, прибавляется по 1 символу через нижнее подчеркивание.

Надеюсь на помощь, спасибо.

Comment: Нет, моя задача на основе строки пользователя потом сгенерировать имя класса. Требования полностью описаны.

Например пользователь вводит строку (задачу):
Первая_задача

Все это трансформируется с S_Pervay_zadacha_S   (перевод строки я делаю с помощью Transliterate). Задача лишь убрать запрещенные спец символы и двусмысленные для перевода буквы (т.е. см выше в вопросе).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы запретить спец.символы, достаточно разрешить только выбранный набор символов: `(letter | digit | "_")*` плюс некоторые русские буквы:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

fullmatch = re.compile(ur'[a-zA-Z0-9_а-щыэ-яА-ЩЫЭ-Я]+$', re.UNICODE).match
```

Пример:

```
>>> bool(fullmatch(u"Первая_задача\n"))
True
>>> bool(fullmatch(u"ё"))
False
```

Это работает даже, если передать `ё` как U+0435 U+0308 комбинацию. При этом U+0435 отдельно (`е`) работает:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> bool(fullmatch(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', u"ё")))
False
>>> bool(fullmatch(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', u"ё")[0]))
True
```

Comment: Это подошло, но на бэке, все равно сделал проверку через словарь, так ка фронт дело не надежное. Спасибо.

Comment: @Arseny что значит ненадёжное? Regex работает как специфицировано. Если найдёте пример, когда оно не работает как вы ожидаете, пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить задачу довольно просто, но не самым производительным путем:

```
def checkName( name ):
    if re.search( r'[\s\(]', name ):
        return False
    else:
        try:
            exec( "class "+name+":\n pass" )
        except:
            return False
    return True
```

Пробуем:

```
>>> checkName( "test" )
True
>>> checkName( "test" )
True
>>> checkName( "*test" )
False
>>> checkName( "try" )
False
```

Comment: Одно из первых имён для проверки: `C(__import__('shutil').rmtree('/'))`. На практике от контекста зависит, когда LBYL, а когда EAFP следует использовать (или их комбинацию).  *"\W не выход - запрещает русские буквы"* указывает, что автор не совсем уверенно с regexs работает (`\W` запрещает не только русские буквы). К примеру, `re.fullmatch(r'\w+', 'русские_буквы')` работает.

Comment: Исправил ошибочное поведение в ответе.  Такое решение может иметь жизнь, потому что не надо углубляться в допустимые символы и невозможность использовать ключевые слова в качестве имени. Без лишних усилий проверяем возможность создания класса с таким именем.

Comment: Вы адаптировали ответ к одному примеру, который я привёл. Повторюсь: достаточно ли regex, можно ли в exec передавать строки и как сильно их пытаться фильтровать предварительно—зависит от контекста: в разных случаях разные trade offs. Вопрос как сейчас поставлен не ясен, поэтому я оставил комментарий к нему, не пытаясь мысли автора через эфир материализовать и писать на этой основе ответ.

Comment: А есть еще варианты, как можно сломать это ? Исключительно из любопытства. Я не придумал пока... Ваш комментарий скорее всего верен. По-крайней мере это следует из текста вопроса.

Comment: да, есть ещё варианты, чтобы злоупотребить `exec()`. В какой-то момент может быть проще regex для идентификатора написать. Хотя даже верный идентификатор не гарантирует, что его значение не эксплуатирует систему каким-либо способом —к примеру, переопределением уже существующего шаблона (если это возможно в контексте scrapy).

Comment: Предложенный варианты не подходят либо не работают. (ver. Python 2.7)